# Generating a table which shows Android and iOs visitors by month? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've resolved a part of the query displaying months and users for Android but I can't seem to find a way to join the users for iOS.

This is the table I'm trying to create form the query:

```
/Months/   IOS   /Android
|June     |324    |123  |
|July     |123    |23   |
|August   |521    |342  |
|September|712    |342  |
```

And this is what I've got

```
/Months   /  IOS  /
|June     |324    |
|July     |123    |
|August   |521    |
|September|712    |
```

This is the query I've been using

```sql
SELECT MONTHNAME(created_at) AS monthy ,
       COUNT(id) as ios 
FROM visitors 
WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3) = 'ios' 
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at);
```

I want to generate data to populate a google chart showing the number of visitors on my application.

I've tried a couple of joins and I've been searching for 6 hours now.

Comment: You need conditional aggregation via `CASE WHEN` constructs.

Comment: Can you show me the structure of your original table or demonstrate the problem using an sql fiddle

Comment: `id     mobile_uuid     created_at
1 adrsdf873 2016-06-15 23:27:07
2 adrsdf763 2016-07-15 23:27:07
3 adrdg6h84 2016-08-15 23:27:07
4 iossdf87g         2016-03-15 23:27:07
5 adrety895 2016-03-15 23:27:07
6 adrd9g87d 2016-03-15 23:27:07`

Comment: @Marlind Parllaku I have updated my answer based on the structure and data provided.Check to see if that is really what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(created_at) MONTH,
(SELECT COUNT(mobile_uuid)  FROM VISITORS V2 
WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3)='ios' 
AND MONTHNAME(V2.created_at)=MONTHNAME(V1.created_at)) AS IOS,
(SELECT COUNT(mobile_uuid)  from VISITORS v3 
WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3)='adr' 
AND MONTHNAME(V3.created_at)=MONTHNAME(V1.created_at)) AS ANDROID
FROM VISITORS V1 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(created_at) ORDER BY created_at
```

Full code

```
CREATE TABLE visitors (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  mobile_uuid VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  created_at DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('adrsdf873', '2016-06-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('adrsdf763', '2016-07-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('adrdg6h84', '2016-08-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('iossdf87g', '2016-03-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('adrety895', '2016-03-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('adrd9g87d', '2016-03-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('iossde88g', '2016-06-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('iossge98g', '2016-07-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('iossue78g', '2016-07-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('adrsref763','2016-07-15 23:27:07');
INSERT INTO visitors (mobile_uuid, created_at) VALUES ('iosscf67g', '2016-08-15 23:27:07');

SELECT MONTHNAME(created_at) MONTH,
(SELECT COUNT(mobile_uuid)  FROM VISITORS V2 
WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3)='ios' 
AND MONTHNAME(V2.created_at)=MONTHNAME(V1.created_at)) AS IOS,
(SELECT COUNT(mobile_uuid)  from VISITORS v3 
WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3)='adr' 
AND MONTHNAME(V3.created_at)=MONTHNAME(V1.created_at)) AS ANDROID
FROM VISITORS V1 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(created_at) ORDER BY created_at
```

The query worked for me

[image]

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a join on subquery

```
select a. monthy, a.ios, b.android 
from ( SELECT   
           MONTHNAME(created_at) AS monthy 
         , COUNT(id) as ios 
    FROM visitors 
    WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3) = 'ios' 
    GROUP BY  MONTH(created_at )) a 
left join ( SELECT   
           MONTHNAME(created_at) AS monthy 
         , COUNT(id) as android
    FROM visitors 
    WHERE MID(mobile_uuid,1,3) = 'adr' 
    GROUP BY  MONTH(created_at) ) b  on a.monthy = b.monthy;
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work...it shows the 3 columns i needed but shows no rows

Comment: I have update the asnwer using left join  if the android is not selected .. any way are you sure the condition   MID(mobile_uuid,1,7) = 'Android'   is right ... id don't know you db content... i have chandgen in MID(mobile_uuid,1,3) = 'adr'